# Getting a "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" error

Tags: python

```
currencies = {'yen': 0.0067, 'bsp': 1.35, 'usd': 0.65, 'ero': 0.85}

if choice == "2":
    Current_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
    amount = input("Type amount you wish to exchange")
    Future_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange into: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
    New_Amount = currencies[Future_Currency] / currencies[Current_Currency] * amount
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please format your code. No one will bother spending time reading your question when it's presented like this.

Comment: SO is not about "could i ask that i get an answer which all i have to do is copy and paste it in" but solving problems.

Comment: yeah well u try and spend your only holiday wasting time because u can't understand and fix one line of code so my holiday is up the swanny

Answer (score 1):

`amount` is a string, since `input()` returns strings. Convert it to a number first, by running it through a numeric type's constructor.

```
amount = float(amount)
```

Comment: so all i do is copy and paste this in im sorry i am a novice and as soon as i have complete this i can start learning it again so wat do i do with it know sorry